# Django rss feedparser to render through a inclusion_tag

Tags: python, django, tags, feedparser

What I'm trying to do is: Have my inclusion tag using feedparser:

```
from django.template import Library
import feedparser
@register.inclusion_tag('home/dashboard.html')
def rss_extract(tag):
    rss = feedparser.parse(tag)       
    return {'rss': rss }
```

get the rss pertaining to each tag (an example would be: http://blog.myblog.com/tag/tag_name/feed/) object that the user has. And return the feed into my dashboard.html:

```
{% for tag in profile.tags.all|slice:':3' %}
    {% rss_extract http://blog.myblog.com/tag/{{ tag }}/feed/ %}
        {% for r in rss.entries|slice:':2' %}
        <li> <a href="{{ r.link }}" target="_blank" title="{{ r.title }}">{{ r.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The error: `Exception Value: rss_extract takes 1 arguments`

How do I get the link to go into the inclusion tag properly?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you replace:

```
http://blog.myblog.com/tag/{{ tag }}/feed/
```

with:

```
http://blog.myblog.com/tag/somethingToTest/feed/
```

If yes, I guess you need to prepare the URL before to pass it. Also it doesn't make sense to "show" it there using {{ }}. That's meant to output HTML.